# how to control the back navigation button in a activity

Tags: android, tabs

I have implemented a tab layout with swipeable views, it has 5 tabs.
in my 1st four tabs i have loaded grid menus. if i select one of those items in da grid it will open a new activity.

in my manifest.xml file i have used this line to navigate it back.

```
android:parentActivityName="xxxxxxx.ActivityMenuGrid"
```

when i select an item in my 2nd,3rd or 4th tabs and press the back navigation button on left top corner of my screen then it will go back to and open up and display the 1st tab, not the tab where i selected the required item.
but if i press the back button in my phone it will navigate me back to the tab where i open the new activity.
how can i navigate my back navigation in my left top corner to the appropriate tab.

```
public class ActivityMenuGrid extends FragmentActivity implements
        ActionBar.TabListener {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    public TabHost myTabHost;

    // Tab titles
    private String[] tabs = { "", "", "", "", "" };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

        // Initilization
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);

        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setTabListener(this)
                .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_tab_p));
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setTabListener(this)
                .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_tab_n));
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setTabListener(this)
                .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_tab_s));
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setTabListener(this)
                .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_tab_pr));
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setTabListener(this)
                .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_tab_pro);
        ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
        bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        // set background for action bar tab
        bar.setStackedBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color
                .parseColor("#f8f8f8")));
        bar.show();

        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);


        /**
         * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
         * */
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);


            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });

    }

    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(startMain);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main_actions, menu);

        // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Take appropriate action for each action item click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.action_search:
            // search action
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

        // getActionBar().setTitle(tab.getText());
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

}
```

im selecting a item from tab2,

[image]

then it will openup new activity. and it has back navigation button.

[image]

when i press the back navigation button then it will go back to the tab1, not tab 2. I want to fix that issue and navigate it to tab2.
FYI- when i press the back navigation hardware button in the phone it will navigate it to tab 2.

any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: i dont understand what you want to do with which back button could you please add screenshots to explain what are you doing it would help

Comment: can u check my updated question please

Answer (score 0):

you have to override the activitys onBackPresed function and have to write the logic to to move to the'desired tab. doing this will prevent your app from close(default navigation on back button pressed) with android hardware back button, also you have to check if you are in desired tab already and pass the event super.onBackPressed(); to the OS to close the app or handle tha default navigation.

Comment: hardware back button is working perfectly. Issue with the screen navigation button, can u help me wt code level to do the overriding part as u mentioned. i have used onBackPressed()

Answer (score 0):

The below code states when you press back button it is starting new activity and you are not overriding that.Check once with that.

```
@Override - > Missing.
    public void onBackPressed() {
            Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(startMain);
        }
```

I would suggest one edit
Try to set position of the tab in **onPageSelected** method and when back pressed check the previous position where it exactly and navigate to it. 
Ex :

```
 static int pos =0;
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                        actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        pos=position;

                    }




     @Override
            public void onBackPressed() {
                try {
                    switch (pos) {
                    case 0: // Means Main Activity : Do Default action
                        super.onBackPressed();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                    case 2:
                    case 3://Other than main tab open previous positioned tab.
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(pos, true);
                        break;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    super.onBackPressed();
                }
            }
```

I had same problem and it worked for me.Glad if i could help you.

Comment: position gives an error in this line, viewPager.setCurrentItem(position, true);

Comment: I have updated the answer. please check. And **case**s are your tab positions. so careful with the no. of tab you have owned. for your case it could be only two.

Comment: i tried this but ths doesnt work as i want. still i get the same output as earlr

Comment: ur code blocking the hardware back navigation when im in tab 2 or 3. How can i change it, when im in tab 2 and when i press back button it should navigate to tab1

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achive it by doing,

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Take appropriate action for each action item click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```